# Replacement cartridge from plumb works

Tags: plumbing

[image: code on cartridge]I bought this cartridge from plumb[image: cartridge] Works that came with the entire brass housing. As you can see the o ring on the back has been lost. I’m unsure if I’m able to buy another ring to go around this? Also I’m worried that a cartridge is going to fail and I’m unable to find another one. Does anyone know how I could solve this problem of do they know where to get a replacement cartridge?

The code on the cartridge is N40HLCKJ0727ZY

UPDATE: I ended up going to menards and finding a different band cartridge for 30 dollars that would work. I couldn’t find an O-ring that is shaped like a “D” and that’s all I really need to fix this cartridge. I ended up buying a tube of silicone and trying to use that to seal. I’m not sure if this is going to work but it’s worth a try I would say.

Comment: You will need to contact plumb works for a replacement O-ring because of the special shape.  They should have replacement rings.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a replacement for your cartridge.  [Zurn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CYP9W4Y)

The important numbers and letters are the N40HLC
N is the type    40 is the size (40mm)